# Expectations and Moments Variance

Tags: statistics, finance, economics, covariance

Suppose $E[X|Y=y] = a + by$ and $V[X|Y=y] = C + dy^2$ where $Y$ is normally distributed with mean μ and variance $σ^2$ . What is $V[X]$?

Answer (score 0):

You already have that
\begin{align*}
E(X \mid Y) &= a + bY\\
E(X^2 \mid Y) &= V(X|Y) + E(X\mid Y)^2 \\
&= c+ d Y^2 + (a+bY)^2.
\end{align*}
By tower law, you have $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$, and subsequently $V(X)$.